# Windows 11 Explorer folder names not centered in medium icon view

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

In Windows 11 22H2, build 22621.2861, my explorer folder names are not centered when the folder view is set to medium (the default). If I change the folder view to large the folder names appear centered correctly. How can I fix this centering issue? I'm assuming this can probably be done in the registry. I attached a picture of the problem. Thanks in advance.

Windows 11 Explorer folder names not centered in medium icon view:

[image: Windows 11 Explorer folder names not centered in medium icon view]